# React-Bootstrap modal not closing. Error: Cannot update a component (`OnboardPage`) while rendering a different component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

I've seen a few other questions with the same error but they don't seem to solve my issue.

I have a react-bootstrap modal that im trying to open from a button inside a child component but I get the following error.

[image: Cannot update component error]

This is the parent component:

**OnboardPage.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Row } from 'react-bootstrap'

import { PersonalDetails } from './personalDetails'
import { EmailVerification } from './emailVerification'
import { Form } from './form'
import { FAQs } from './faq'
import { LeftCol, RightCol } from './styles'
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'

const OnboardPage = props => {
    const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);
    const handleClose = (showValue) => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = (showValue) => setShow(true);

    return (
        <Row>
            <LeftCol md={8}>
                <PersonalDetails parentShowFn={handleShow}/>
                <Form />
            </LeftCol>
            <RightCol md={4}>
                <EmailVerification />
                <FAQs />
            </RightCol>
            <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                  <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                  <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
                    Close
                  </Button>
                  <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
                    Save Changes
                  </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </Row>
    )
}

export default OnboardPage
```

Child Component:

**Personaldetails.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'

import { colors } from '../../../../res'
import { TitleText, CommonText, SubHeadingText } from '../../../commons/freelancer/texts'
import { Container, TitleRow, DetailsRow, DetailsItem, EditBtn } from './personalDetailsStyles'
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
// import EditDetailsModal from './EditDetailsModal'

const PersonalDetails = ({parentShowFn}) => {

    return (

        <Container>
        <TitleRow>
            <TitleText>Personal Details</TitleText>
            <EditBtn onClick={parentShowFn()}>Edit</EditBtn>
        </TitleRow>
    </Container>
    )

}
    

export default PersonalDetails
```

I've seen the stack trace and i believe the problem lies here:

[image: Stack Trace Snippet]

But I can't figure out what it is :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong with the Edit Button `onClick` prop

```
<Button onClick={parentShowFn()}>Edit</Button>
```

What this does is: on each render of `PersonalDetails`, this will just set the state for the `show` state back in `OnboardPage`to `true`, therefore when the Modal `onHide` event is fired, state updates will cause re-renders, `PersonalDetails` will be re-rendered and therefore set the state of show to `true` again due to the above code

Furthermore, `handleShow` does not return anything therefore subsequent clicks on the Edit Button will not do anything (i.e., `onClick={undefined}`).

I suggest you refactor the `onClick` prop value to return a function

```
<Button onClick={()=>parentShowFn()}>Edit</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks that fixes it, but now my modal doesn't seem to open. Guess that's another issue though.